# Currency field and rendered attribute do NOT seem to work together at all

Tags: visualforce, rendered, currency

I've just spent the better part of my day trying to sort this out. Seems that if i have a Currency type in my custom object (`mortgages__c`), there is no way to get the Page to gather input and reflect it back into my custom object IF I HAVE A RENDERED ATTRIBUTE ON IT.
E.g:

```
< apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
  < apex:outputLabel value="Total Liens $"  rendered="{!isRealAsset}"/ >
  < apex:inputField value="{!obj.mortgages__c}" rendered="{!isRealAsset}"/ >
< /apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

Where my record of custom object is "obj" with a field `mortgages__c` and
`isRealAsset()` is a Boolean method that returns a true or false.

I've tried to put the render on the pageBlockSectionItem. 
I've tried to wrap it all in an outputPanel with a rendered attribute.
I've tried a bunch of different things and the ONLY thing that works is to have `rendered="true"`. (Not very useful!) That is the only way the value will be reflected back in my object.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Super annoyed so i hope i'm just doing something careless. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want these fields to be visible only on some condition ? Rendered will only make them visible/invisible.

Comment: I am not able to understand the reason for using rendered in your case. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Out of left field, is the `isRealAsset()` called `getIsRealAsset()` in the controller? I seem to recall seeing something weird before where using `is` to start a method compiles but doesn't work in practice.

If the method is just called `isRealAsset` then try renaming it to `getIsRealAsset`, I suspect it'll start working!

Comment: Dave-Yes, i need to have the label and field visible only when "isRealAssest()" returns true. I'll try renaming it to getIsRealAsset() and see what happens.

Comment: It looks like it didn't help to rename "isRealAsset()" to getisRealAsset() or anything else. That would have been nice. Its a simple function checking a String value and returning true or false (but changed it to "assetIsReal()" just in case):                                                      public  Boolean  assetIsReal {                          
        get{if (assetTypeChosen == 'ASSET-REAL') return true; return false;} set;}

Comment: So which way is it going? Always rendering the field or always not rendering it? Or does it switch but doesn't let you gather input

Comment: So which way is it going - does it always render or not? Or, is it that it is rendering but you can't get the input from it when using the rendered attribute?

Comment: The rendering part works absolutely fine but, oddly enough, if i have any kind of "Rendered" attribute on the inputField (even if i put the rendered on the pageBlockSectionItem or enclose *all* of them in an outputPanel), the mortgages__c will not reflect the new value. One caveat, if i simply put rendered="true" (rather than any conditional), the value IS reflected in mortgages__c.